# 'Node' does not name a type Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list. I'm getting 'Node' does not name a type at line 8 and line 15. Also at lines 33 and 34 I'm getting first and last was not declared in this scope. This is probably a result of Node not being recognized.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Linked_List {
public:
  Linked_List();
  void print_list();
  Node* find_kth(int k); // Line 8
  void insert_front(T d);
  void insert_back(T d);
  void delete_front();
  void delete_back();
private:
  int length;
  Node* first, last; // Line 15
  class Node {
  public:
    Node(Node* n = NULL, T d = T{});
  private:
    Node* next;
    int data;
  };
};

template <typename T>
typename Linked_List<T>::Node(Node* n, T d) {
  next = n;
  data = d;
}

template <typename T>
Linked_List<T>::Linked_List() {
  first = NULL; // Line 33
  last = NULL; // Line 34
  length = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::print_list() {
  Node* temp = first;
  if (length > 0) {
    std::cout << first->data << std::endl;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
    temp = temp->next;
    std::cout << temp->data << std::endl;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::insert_front(T d) {
  Node* new_node = new Node{first, d};
  Node* temp = new_node;
  first = temp;
}


int main() {
  Linked_List<int> l_l;
  //l_l.insert_front(10);
  //  l_l.print_list();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to declare the node class before using it in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two errors are the result of he first two and will disappear once you solve them. The first two errors are because you reference the symbol `Node` before declaring it.

Also, the way you are implementing the constructor of `Node` is incorrect.

```
class Linked_List {
  class Node {              // <-- move it here
  public:
    Node(Node* n = NULL, T d = T{});
  private:
    Node* next;
    int data;
  };
public:
  Linked_List();
  void print_list();
  Node* find_kth(int k);
  void insert_front(T d);
  void insert_back(T d);
  void delete_front();
  void delete_back();
private:
  int length;
  Node* first, last;
};
```

The constructor of `Node` that you are trying to implement outside of the class's body should be like this:

```
template <typename T>
Linked_List<T>::Node::Node(Node* n, T d) {
  next = n;
  data = d;
}
```

As you see here `Linked_List<T>::Node` is the name of the class, then the second `Node` is the constructor's name, and the inner `Node` is the parameter's type but in the latter we don't need to say again `Linked_List<T>::Node` because the scope of the name was already determined.

Comment: I thought that order didn't matter within a class definition. But it seems you are correct it fixed my problem.

Comment: @user1692570 indeed what you say is true about member variables and methods, but not about nested classes :)